# iReport - How to prevent texfield go to next page

Tags: jasper-reports

I need help!

When Textfield Text is too big and does not fit all the content on the page, it is automatically moved to the next page, can anyone help?

The result is the following:
[image]

The structure of the report is as follows:

structure of the report
[image]

The expected result would be to completely fill the first page, and then break to next.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent page split between details band in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543245/how-to-prevent-page-split-between-details-band-in-jasperreports)

Answer (score 2):

You can manage your detail band selecting it and change the property Split type as the following image:

[image: Split type options]

The meanings of three options:

**STRETCH:**

The band is allowed to split, but never within its declared height. This means the band splits only when its content stretches.

**PREVENT:**

Prevents the band from splitting on first break attempt. On subsequent pages/columns, the band is allowed to split, to avoid infinite loops.

**IMMEDIATE:**

The band is allowed to split anywhere, as early as needed, but not before at least one element being printed on the current page/column.

You can see [**here**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/SplitTypeEnum.html)